# How to convert template variables to custom data in magento 2

Tags: magento2, price, template, email-templates, variables

I have configured a back-end screen where I will enter a string as

`{{price}} for guest user. click here {{sign_up}}`.

So after I fetch the field value I want to dynamically replace the `{{price}}` variable to some custom price and `{{sign_up}}` to a **cms page link**.

Can anybody help me on how to do this?
thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have found a code to parse the variables using core php code.

```
public function findReplace($string, $find, $replace)
{
    if (preg_match("/[a-zA-Z\_]+/", $find)) {
        return (string) preg_replace("/\{\{(\s+)?($find)(\s+)?\}\}/", $replace, $string);
    } else {
        throw new \Exception("Find statement must match regex pattern: /[a-zA-Z]+/");
    }
}
```

this code can parse it and replace the values to what we want.